# Use online map offline in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, bing-maps, offline

> How to use Bing online map offline in power  bi?

> > Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-map-tips-and-tricks) below, you could use latitude / longitude coordinates for the bubble maps and thereby avoid sending data to Bing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no offline support for the maps in Power BI.